# Parallel processing - does the slaves generate the data set?

Tags: c++, mpi

In my parallel programming book, I came across this code that says the slaves generate the data set, however, I think the master acutally generates the data set.

This line in particular is why I believe that master generates the data set.

```
for (i=0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) 
        numbers[i] = i;
```

Can someone confirm if master or slaves generate the data set?

```
#include "mpi.h" 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

#define TRIALS 20 
#define ARRAY_SIZE 1000000 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    int myid, numprocs; 
    double startwtime, endwtime; 
    int namelen; 
    int* numbers = new int[ARRAY_SIZE]; 
    int i, j, sum, part_sum; 
    int s, s0, startIndex, endIndex; 
    double totalTime; 

    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME]; 

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv); 
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numprocs); 
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myid); 
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name,&namelen); 

    fprintf(stderr,"Process %d on %s\n", myid, processor_name); 
    fflush(stderr); 

    for (i=0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) 
        numbers[i] = i; 

    if (myid == 0) 
    { 
        s = (int) floor(ARRAY_SIZE/numprocs); 
        s0 = s + ARRAY_SIZE%numprocs; 
        //printf("s=%d , s0= %d\n", s, s0); 
    } 

    MPI_Bcast(&s, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
    MPI_Bcast(&s0, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 

    startIndex = s0 + (myid - 1)*s; 
    endIndex = startIndex + s; 

    totalTime = 0; 

    for (j = 1; j <= TRIALS; j++) 
    { 
        if (myid == 0) 
        { 
            startwtime = MPI_Wtime(); 
        } 

        sum = 0; 
        part_sum = 0; 

        if (myid == 0) // master 
        { 
            // compute sum of master's numbers 
            for (i = 0; i < s0; i++) 
            { 
                part_sum += numbers[i]; 
            } 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            for (i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) 
            { 
                part_sum += numbers[i]; 
            } 
        } 
        MPI_Reduce(&part_sum, &sum, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
        if (myid == 0) 
        { 
            double runTime; 
            endwtime = MPI_Wtime(); 
            runTime = endwtime - startwtime; 

            printf("Trial %d : Execution time (sec) = %f\n", j, runTime); 
            printf("Sum = %d \n", sum); 
            totalTime += runTime; 
        } 
    } // end for 
    if (myid == 0) 
        printf("Average time for %d trials = %f", TRIALS, totalTime/TRIALS); 

    MPI_Finalize(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the master *and* the slaves generate the entire array. You have to remember that your program runs on all nodes and the part of the code in question doesn't distinguish between master/slave. So the wording of your book isn't wrong, but it could be clarified. :)

Comment: In essence, yes. MPI processes are guaranteed to have started and have a copy of the argument list only after `MPI_Init` has returned successfully.